# OracleDB - InstantClient/SQL Plus - Select, Spool to File, Maximum Size?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have downloaded Oracle's instantclient.
I noticed that when I use SQLPlus and do a `select count(*)`, using certain joined tables and WHERE parameters, I get a value like ~78000+ entries.
However, when I spool to file, I only get 6474 entries in the csv.
The spooled file size is 645 kb.
I am not having any issues with my Harddrive, RAM, or CPU in terms of performance or capacity.

I have also tried connecting through Excel, using ODBC with the same instantclient files and it gives the same output.

The way I see it, I think it might be something to do with the driver or Oracle's instantclient...

### Question

What is going on? How can I get the full set of data?
Does it have anything to do with Pagesize or Linesize?
Am I using the right SQL command `select count(*)` for number of rows/records?
Am I reaching some sort of Maximum size limitation?

Comment: How much freespace do you have your disk or your folder? I have encountered a similar error in the past when the unix folder I was spooling to didn't have enough space allocated to me.

Comment: No issues with Harddrive, RAM, or CPU on my end.

Comment: What is the size of the spooled file in kb?

Comment: You are literally just putting `select count(*) from ( ... )` around the query you're using for the spool, you aren't modifying the query itself? There is no Oracle-imposed limit and pagesize and linesize won't be an issue. If you don't have space or disk quotas issues then it's a bit odd. I suppose it's possible there's a line break issue; but the file size and line count suggest not, as does getting the same result through ODBC. Have you examined the file, and compared with a few rows from the raw query? Is the last line in the file complete?

Comment: I suspect he's hitting a special HEX character in one of the tables that is causes the spool to stop. Unfortunately, without the data in front of me, I can't answer the question accurately.